# Fourier Series Expansion and its derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

I am studying the Fourier series in my real analysis course and I am stuck on some questions...

I have a function $f(x)$ in the trigonometric system given as:

$f(x)\sim \frac{a_0}2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\bigl(a_n\cos nx + b_n\sin nx\bigr)$

and I want to show that the derivative of this function is:

$f'(x)\sim \sum_{n=1}^\infty\bigl(nb_n\cos nx -n a_n\sin nx\bigr)$

It can be proved easily using the definitions but my question is how do we know if we can expand f' in the trig system or not? Based on my current knowledge I think we need f' to be in $L^2$ so that the expansion can be considered.

There are some conditions given on $f$ but I can't find a way to prove that $f'$ is in $L^2$. The conditions given are that $f$ is $L^2[-\pi, \pi]$ and is $2\pi$ periodic and has a continuous derivative. Can you help me prove that $f'$ is also in $L^2$? I tried to use Jordan's test as well but can't see a way to prove that f' is of bounded variation either.

Comment: Continuous derivative!

Comment: @TedShifrin Does this mean my function is of bounded variation?

Comment: Continuous functions belong to $L^2.$

Comment: Can you please provide me with reference to the proof of such theorem? As per my understanding, $f$ is in $L^2$ if $f$ is measurable (approached by a sequence of step functions) and $f^2$ is in $L$ (written as the difference of two upper functions) @RyszardSzwarc

Comment: If $f'$ is continuous on $[0,2\pi]$ then it is bounded.  Therefore it  is Riemann  integrable (standard integral) for continuous function. There is no need to discuss measureability.